# Windows Forms text area with by-line editing capabilities (like Path environment variable)

Tags: winforms

I am looking to design a textbox which is populated from the settings file of my Windows Forms Application.
The settings look like this:

```
<setting name="TXT1" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Foo</value>
</setting>
<setting name="TXT2" serializeAs="String">
    <value>Bar</value>
</setting>
```

The textarea is supposed to load each String value and put it in a new line ("Foo" and "Bar").
It shall also have edit capabilities where each line, when clicked becomes a editable textfield with cursor. Just like the edit capabilities from the path system variable [in this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xCw7w.png).
A button next to the textbox shall add a new line to the textarea and open the editable textfield.

I'm not asking for someone to write my code, just need a hint, if there is such a kind of special textarea element within .NET that offers these by-line edit capability. 
Thanks!!

**Edit**
Okay, looks like what I'm looking for is an editable ListBox.

Comment: TextBox has a MultiLine property. Isn't this enough?

Comment: I would like that when you click an item in the list that you can edit it. just like the editing of the path environment variable.

Comment: [TreeView.LabelEdit Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.treeview.labeledit).